# scripts on a windows remote desktop keep having connection issues

Tags: node.js, terminal, cloud, vps, remote-desktop

I purchased a VPS for Windows 2019, which runs 24/7 on the cloud. I connected to it with MS Remote Desktop, and on it I am running a nodejs script that loops forever, doing things every 5 minutes. I leave the script running in the terminal, and then I close my remote desktop program.

When I log back on the next day, I see the script ran for several hours, but errored out with "ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error.  code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'". See attached.

Is there any way to fix this? This is running on Microsoft Server 2019, and when I go to "power & Sleep" settings, I see it is set to "Never"

[image: error pic]